# Closed sets and finite sets

Tags: real-analysis

I was wondering if someone could clear this up for me. According to Trench(A real Analysis book), A set is closed if and only if it contains all its limit points. It also further said that all finite sets are closed. But in my mind(I may be wrong), there can be a finite set that will have interior points but not limit points. Which makes it open, not closed. I wonder if I am missing something.

Again, does the definition of a a closed set tell us that every point is a limit point? I thought some of its points are also boundary points.

thanks

Comment: "here can be a finite set that will have interior points" - no there can't. Any subset of the reals with non-empty interior contains a proper interval.

Comment: With respect to the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ (which is the topology that makes sense in a class on real analysis), any set with a non-empty interior is uncountable.

Comment: Where does the set live? Is it a subset of $\mathbb{R}$? Or a subset of a metric space or topological space?

Comment: a subset of R@EclipseSun

Comment: A finite set contains only isolated points, not limit points or interior points. Moreover, it doesn't HAVE any limit points (in the set or not). So it vacuously contains all of its limit points, hence it's closed.

Comment: Pardon me if I am asking stupid questions. but if a finite set contains only isolated points, those same points can't be limit points right? And what do you mean by vacuously contains all its limit points@Bungo

Comment: A set that doesn't have *any* limit points must be closed because there aren't any limit points *not* in the set. So the set contains all of its limit points. (All zero of them.) So a finite set must be closed because it *doesn't* have any limit points.

Comment: To *not* be closed, there must be some limit points that are *not* in the set.  That's not possible if there aren't any limit points in the first place.

Comment: @fleeblood thank you so much I get it now

Comment: @Spirit_bird If you don't like the "vacuously closed" argument, you might prefer to show that the complement of $A$ is open. This is pretty easy: if $x \in A^c$, then the distance between $x$ and any point in $A$ is nonzero. Since there are only finitely many such points, the set $\{|a-x| : a \in A\}$ has a nonzero minimum, call it $\delta$. Then the interval of radius $\delta/2$ centered at $x$ contains no point of $A$, hence this interval is contained in $A^c$, hence $A^c$ is open, hence $A$ is closed.

Comment: But it actually depends on the topologoy.  If you use to trivial topology that R and $\emptyset $ are the only open sets, then $R $ and $\emptyset $ are the only closed sets.   Finite sets are not closed because all points are limit points of every set.

Comment: If the set has no limit points,then it will be closed automatically.Because it automatically will contain all its limits points then.

Comment: yea I understand the fact that R and empty sets are both closed and open. thanks @fleeblood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working out of a real analysis book, let's only talk about the real numbers for this problem. We know that a limit point $x$ of a set $A$ is some point where there is a sequence of members if $A$, call it $\lbrace a_n \rbrace$, where each $a_i$ gets closer and closer to the limit point $x$ as $i \rightarrow \infty$ , i.e. $|x-a_i| < \varepsilon$ for arbitrarily small $\varepsilon$. Notice that these points $a_i$ can $\underline{\text{not}}$ be the same as $x$, also by definition.

With this definition in place, we say a set $A$ is closed if and only if it contains all of it's limit points; e.g. we know the interval $(0,1)$ is not closed because the sequence $\lbrace \frac{1}{n} \rbrace$ converges to $0$, but $0 \not\in (0,1)$. We could also show that $[0,1]$ is closed if we wished. Notice that with these two examples, sequences are easy to construct, because we have lots of numbers between $0$ and $1$ to make sequences with. (note also that we may defined closed as $A^{\prime} \subseteq A$, where $A^{\prime}$ is the set of limit points of $A$; this may come in handy later).

Now let us consider a (vastly) smaller set; $\lbrace 1,2,3,7 \rbrace$. As a perfectly nice subset of $\mathbb{R}$, we can then start to talk about it's openness or closedness with respect to the topology on the $\mathbb{R}$. So, if we wanted to know if $A$ is closed, let's find some limit points! Particularly, let's see if $1$ is a limit point.

Well, if we take a sequence of numbers from this set, we'll notice something strange; all the elements of any $\lbrace a_n \rbrace$ will be either $1,2,3,7$. With this in mind, think of how we can make a sequence that gets closer and closer to $1$ but never touches $1$; in fact, it turns out that we can't, because there are no elements arbitrarily close to $1$ in our set which are not $1$ itself! So, we have that $1$ is not a limit point.

If we extend this to all the other elements, we then see that $A = \lbrace 1,2,3,7 \rbrace$ has no limit points! Then, because it contains all $\underline{\text{NONE}}$ of them (vacuously), we know that $A$ is a closed set. So, what we have found is that some sets don't have any limit points, and because of this that makes them closed. If the bit about vacuous truth is confusing, then we only need to know that $A^{\prime} = \varnothing$, and then clearly $\varnothing \subseteq A$, and $A$ is again closed.

Comment: oh okay, I think I get it. You are trying to say that by definition a closed set has all its limit points. The opposite will be that it has only some of its limit points which makes it open. But It has no limit points to begin with. So, VACUOUSLY, it is closed! But if it were a sequence or something then it will contain all its limit points as said in the definition. Right?? Did I get it?

Comment: @Spirit_bird your conception of vacuous seems perfect!! :D In fact, if we have any finite set of points, or any infinite set of points that don't get "closer and closer" to each other (and so has no limit points), then you can use that same logic to say it's closed!! :)